# MarkLogic 8 - Dynamic XPath

Tags: xpath, marklogic

I have a reporting requirement where a query will be exactly the same except for a few **XPath** expressions depending on what column needs to be filtered on in a where clause.

> where $record/firstName eq $firstName

vs

> where $record/lastName eq $lastName

How can I use a dynamic **XPath** so I can use the same code for both and pass in the path as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could use [xdmp:unpath()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unpath) for this case.

Comment: I just did an implementation that is similar to what Tutan is asking for, and `xdmp:unpath()` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Queries and XPaths are fundamentally different:

- Queries look for words or values in named indexes to retrieve documents.
- XPaths find nodes within retrieved JSON or XML documents.

A subset of XPaths (known as searchable expressions) can be treated as queries behind the scenes, but there's no particular advantage to the XPaths in those cases -- the same thing can be expressed as a query.

With that as context, one possibility is to construct the queries dynamically, nesting element or JSON scope (aka container) queries to express the path.  Would that meet your requirements?  If not, can you expand on the use case?

One thing to be aware of:  for precise scope queries, you either have to turn on positions or execute a filtered query.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Let me put it another way..
I have ~150 lines of XQuery where the only line that changes is:
where $record/firstName eq $firstName
How can I re-use the code without copying/pasting and still change that one line based on the report I need?

Comment: This is a corb job if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  One alternative would be to specify the dynamic query as a serialized cts:query string for an external variable. Then, the XQuery module can deserialize the query using the cts:query() constructor and use the deserialized query along the static queries in the cts.query tree. Another alternative would be to template the XQuery module on the client, replacing a placeholder with the dynamic query before invoking CORB.